# How can I call an angular service from within a custom rxjs operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I’m writing a custom rxjs operator to handle logging HttpClient response errors. My instinct is to put the custom operator in its own file that I’d just include where needed. However, that puts it out of the “Angular world” so how would it get access to my Angular logging service?

Comment: Why not use an interceptor for the error logging in HttpClient? Or do you want to add conditional error logging.

Comment: Yeah it needs to be a little more contextual than an interceptor could provide. For instance I don’t want it to log if it retried and succeeded. Or if one API call failed, but a secondary one retrieved data.

Comment: You could probably try to hack it and have the interceptor function be part of a service class. This way you could inject the logging service inside the operator service but it would also require for you to inject the actual operator wherever you use it. Also *this* would probably not bind correctly inside the operator unless you do it the ES6 method way like this: operator: () => {} instead of operator() {}. This is just a hack I thought about. Not sure if it's correct or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor is one possible solution. Another alternative is create your own http service which i prefer

```
class Http{
   constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
   logging = (res)=>tap(res=>log(res))
   preIntercept(options)=>options
   post(options){ 
      options=preIntercept(options)
      return http.post(options).pipe(logging)
   } 
}
```

It just gives you more flexibility, and code are more explicit. With default interceptor you will run into a lot of `if else` cases because every http call is going through this centralized hub.